# Error C2280 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing this code and for some reason I get error C2280 saying I'm trying to reference a deleted function. Don't exactly know what that means. Also every time I try to reference using the ampersand sign for in it keeps saying it expects a ")" then it doesn't let me pass `menuList[]` so it says it's undefined and that `getData()` has too many arguments. Any clues on what is going on? Currently running VS 13

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std; 

struct menuItemType
{
string ItemName;
double ItemPrice;
};

void getData(ifstream in&, menuItemType menuList[]); \\ doesn't let me pass in here 
void showMenu();
void printCheck();


int main()
  {
     menuItemType menuList[8];
   menuList[8].ItemName; 
   menuList[8].ItemPrice;

   ifstream in;
   in.open("Menu.txt");

   getData(in,menuList); \\ states that it has too many arguments 

   return 0;
}

void getData(ifstream in&, menuItemType menuList[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        in >> menuList[i].ItemName >> menuList[i].ItemPrice; \\ this is where menuList is undefined 
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to give full, exact errors with locations included. And in addition to the compiler errors, you're also accessing your array out of bounds. You're also asking for an overrun by reading values and never seeing if they're going to be stored *in* the array.

Comment: Don't expect us to know what "Error C2280" means. Including the relevant portion of the error message in your title, and the *entire* error message in your question, would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void getData(ifstream in&, menuItemType menuList[]);
```

The correct pass-by-reference syntax should be:

```
void getData(ifstream &in, menuItemType menuList[]);
//                    ^^^
```

Also the array `menuList` has only 8 elements, so it's illegal to access `menuList[8]` because  the array index starts from `0` in C++.